How can I interface a large I beam and wooden top plate?
I am trying to build a large mezzanine in my residential attached garage. Material cost is my main concern. It will be supported by a heavy W10 steel beam (because I got a good deal).
I'd like to set my beam and joists at the right level to avoid a step up/down if I ever add doors into the house and/or convert this into finished space. I'd also like to set my joists on top of my beam if possible so I can install a beam trolley and probably save on extra joist hangers.
The problem: My beam interferes with the double top-plate of the crawlspace wall. That is, where my beam goes into the wall to sit on a jack stack, the web directly bisects the existing top plate.
The question - What are smarter options for making these fit? Cutting the top plate, even just an inch wide to fit the beam webbing, feels dumb. Cutting a ~5" notch out of the beam web feels even sillier.
Some alternatives I've evaluated:

Setting joists between the ibeam flanges and moving the whole thing up into the existing joist space. con - No beam trolley
Setting the beam below the crawlspace top plate and using 16" joists. con - $
Just accepting the step-up/down. con - Everybody hates step-downs



You're overthinking. Just cut out the plates.
That's how it's always done. The beam ties into the wall and provides the lateral stability that the plates might have (if there weren't already all kinds of other things tied into the wall doing the same).
More specifically, you'd frame in a "beam pocket" by gapping the plates the width of the beam (plus a little for easier fitment). Studs outside the pocket extend fully to the normal top plate. Post studs stop where they need to for the beam.
Hack away. Cut out just for the beam web if that makes you happy or provides important backing or support for something else.

Sorry to be thick. Can you please elaborate a bit for me? ICC 602.6.1 seems pretty un-cool with this. It is a load-bearing wall between the house and garage, supporting interior ijoists. Thanks.

Elaborate on what? Your alternative is to only bear the beam partway into the intersecting wall. It may only need 3" of bearing, but it may need 4-1/2". I'm not sure. At any rate, beams intersect exterior walls all the time. There has to be some way to handle it, right? Get someone on site if you want more confidence.
